# Improvement of table scaling

Tags: tables, formatting, vertical-alignment

I currently have the following table, including other tables, images and some text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\specialcelltwo}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
    \centering\underline{\bfseries{Vergleichsspannungen}}
    \addvbuffer[0.3cm 0.2cm]
    {\begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                Hypothese & Allgemeine Richtung & Hauptspannungsrichtung\\\hline
                NH & $\frac{1}{2}(\left|\sigma_x\right| + \sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2})$ & $\left|\sigma_1\right|$\\\hline
                SH & $\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2}$ & $\left|\sigma_1\right|$\\\hline
                GEH & $\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + 3\tau_{xy}^2}$  & $\left|\sigma_1\right|$ \\\hline
            \end{tabular}&
            %some image \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.23]{einachsig.png}}
            &
            \specialcelltwo{Einachsiger ebener\\ Spannungszustand\\(Spröde)}\\
    \end{tabular}}
    \vspace*{0.3cm}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hspace*{0.28cm}\scalebox{0.645}{%
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                Hypothese & Allgemeine Richtung & Hauptspannungsrichtung\\\hline
                NH &$\frac{(\sigma_x + \sigma_y) + \sqrt{(\sigma_x - \sigma_y)^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2}}{2}$ & $\text{max}(\left|\sigma_1\right|,\left|\sigma_2\right|)$\\\hline
                SH & \specialcelltwo{$\sqrt{(\sigma_x - \sigma_y)^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2}$ (für $\sigma_x\sigma_y \le \tau_{xy}^2$)\\$\frac{(\sigma_x + \sigma_y) + \sqrt{(\sigma_x - \sigma_y)^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2}}{2}$ (für $\sigma_x\sigma_y > \tau_{xy}^2$)} & \specialcelltwo{$\text{max} \{\left|\sigma_1\right|, \left|\sigma_2\right|\}$ (gleiche Vorzeichen)\\$(\left|\sigma_1\right| -  \left|\sigma_2\right|)$ (unterschiedliche Vorzeichen)}\\\hline
                GEH & $\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2 -\sigma_x\sigma_y + 3\tau_{xy}^2}$ & $\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1\sigma_2}$ \\\hline
        \end{tabular}}&
        %some image \hspace{0.2cm}\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.175]{zweiachsig.png}}
        &
        \specialcelltwo{Zweiachsiger ebener\\ Spannungszustand\\(Duktil)}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \addvbuffer[-0.1cm 0.2cm]{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \scalebox{0.577}{%
                \hspace*{1.2cm}
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    Hypothese & Allgemeine Richtung & Hauptspannungsrichtung\\\hline
                    NH &  & $\text{max}\{\left|\sigma_1\right|,\left|\sigma_2\right|, \left|\sigma_3\right|\}$ \\\hline
                    SH &  & $\text{max}\{\left|\sigma_1 - \sigma_2\right|,\left|\sigma_2 - \sigma_3\right|, \left|\sigma_3 - \sigma_1\right|\}$  \\\hline
                    GEH & $\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2 + \sigma_z^2 - \sigma_x\sigma_y - \sigma_x\sigma_z - \sigma_y\sigma_z + 3(\tau_{xy}^2 + \tau_{xz}^2 + \tau_{yz}^2)}$ & $\sqrt{\frac{(\sigma_1-\sigma_2)^2 + (\sigma_2 - \sigma_3)^2 + (\sigma_3 - \sigma_1)^2}{2}}$   \\\hline
            \end{tabular}}&
            %some image \hspace{0.2cm}\raisebox{-.45\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{dreiachsig.png}}
            &
            \specialcelltwo{Dreiachsiger räumlicher\\ Spannungszustand\\(Duktil)}
            \vspace*{0.2cm}
    \end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

With the images it looks like this: [image]

I'm not happy about the way that I scaled the tables as it was very finicky and the scaled down tables look grainy. Also, the equations inside the tables don't fit the cell height, and I can't find a way to fix this issue.

Are there better ways to generate tables with fixed widths and heights that fit the size of the content within the cells?

Sorry for the horrible code, but this was the only way I could get the result I wanted. I'm grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your request of 1) fixed width, 2) fixed height, *and* 3) fits the contents, is overconstraining the problem.  The result you show is what you get when you fix all 3.  Perhaps letting one of the constraints slip would open up novel solutions. (suggestion: allow height to vary somewhat)

Comment: please extend your code sniped to small complete document! information about page layout is important information at table scaling.

Comment: @Zarko I edited the code snippet. Note that the tables are misaligned because of the missing images.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The main issue is the formatting of the size of the tables themselves, which includes width and height of the table. Fitting the contents was just another issue that I had with the current layout, but it's rather optional for now.

Comment: never apply scaling to tables unless it's an absolute last resort (and even then don't do it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What else would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid scaling tables, this still has a couple of warnings about overfull but is closer to fitting. I also removed spurious `\left\right` which add extra horizontal space you can't afford here, and used `\max` instead of `\text{max}` to get operator spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\specialcelltwo}[2][c]{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}\scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \centering
\footnotesize \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\underline{\bfseries Vergleichsspannungen }
\medskip

    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|p{5.6cm}|p{5.7cm}|@{}}
                \hline
                Hypothese & Allgemeine Richtung & Hauptspannungsrichtung\\\hline
                NH & $\frac{1}{2}(\lvert\sigma_x\rvert + \sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2})$ & $\lvert\sigma_1\rvert$\\\hline
                SH & $\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2}$ & $\lvert\sigma_1\rvert$\\\hline
                GEH & $\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + 3\tau_{xy}^2}$  & $\lvert\sigma_1\rvert$ \\\hline
            \end{tabular}&
            \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
            &
            \specialcelltwo{Einachsiger\\ ebener\\ Spannungszustand\\(Spröde)}\\
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace*{0.3cm}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|p{5.6cm}|p{5.7cm}|@{}}
                \hline
                Hypothese & Allgemeine Richtung & Hauptspannungsrichtung\\\hline
                NH &$\frac{(\sigma_x + \sigma_y) + \sqrt{(\sigma_x - \sigma_y)^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2}}{2}$ & $\max(\lvert\sigma_1\rvert,\lvert\sigma_2\rvert)$\\\hline
                SH & \specialcelltwo{$\sqrt{(\sigma_x - \sigma_y)^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2}$ (für $\sigma_x\sigma_y \le \tau_{xy}^2$)\\$\frac{(\sigma_x + \sigma_y) + \sqrt{(\sigma_x - \sigma_y)^2 + 4 \tau_{xy}^2}}{2}$ (für $\sigma_x\sigma_y > \tau_{xy}^2$)} &
  $\max \{\lvert\sigma_1\rvert, \lvert\sigma_2\rvert\}$ (gleiche Vorzeichen)

$(\lvert\sigma_1\rvert -  \lvert\sigma_2\rvert)$ (unterschiedliche Vorzeichen)\\\hline
                GEH & $\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2 -\sigma_x\sigma_y + 3\tau_{xy}^2}$ & $\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1\sigma_2}$ \\\hline
        \end{tabular}&
                    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
        &
        \specialcelltwo{Zweiachsiger\\ ebener\\ Spannungszustand\\(Duktil)}\\
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace*{0.3cm}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|p{5.6cm}|p{5.7cm}|@{}}
                    \hline
                    Hypothese & Allgemeine Richtung & Hauptspannungsrichtung\\\hline
                    NH &  & $\max\{\lvert\sigma_1\rvert,\lvert\sigma_2\rvert, \lvert\sigma_3\rvert\}$ \\\hline
                    SH &  & $\max\{\lvert\sigma_1 - \sigma_2\rvert,\lvert\sigma_2 - \sigma_3\rvert, \lvert\sigma_3 - \sigma_1\rvert\}$  \\\hline
                    GEH & $\sqrt{
\begin{gathered}\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2 + \sigma_z^2 - \sigma_x\sigma_y- \sigma_x\sigma_z - \sigma_y\sigma_z\\
\quad + 3(\tau_{xy}^2 + \tau_{xz}^2 + \tau_{yz}^2)
\end{gathered}}$ &
 $\sqrt{\frac{(\sigma_1-\sigma_2)^2 + (\sigma_2 - \sigma_3)^2 + (\sigma_3 - \sigma_1)^2}{2}}$   \\\hline
            \end{tabular}&
            \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}
            &
            \specialcelltwo{Dreiachsiger\\ räumlicher\\ Spannungszustand\\(Duktil)}
            \vspace*{0.2cm}
    \end{tabular}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks almost like I want it to! I'm not familiar with the array environment, but is there a way to center the contents horizontally (and maybe even vertically)?